# Ideas for how to use the minor(add9) chord

Tags: chords, intervals

I've started writing a piece of music for guitar which starts with a really cool arpeggio with the Dm (add9) chord. However, I don't really know how to progress from here and I'm noodling with a few things and would like assistance. I've toyed with moving on to a Gsus4 arpeggio or something of the like.

What pieces of music use the minor add9 as a root chord that i can look at for ideas and how can it be used within a piece of music when it is the root? I want to create a minor sounding piece which builds tension and any ideas as to how to work this in would be great as I know I've got a good start but need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: 'Laura' (jazz standard) springs to mind - even though the chords are simple, but the melody puts the 'add9' bit in.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Music.SE! You can read [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what questions are considered "on topic." Questions asking for recommendations of songs which fit particular criteria are off topic because they're often too specific to help future users. You might be able to rephrase this question by asking what functions a `min9` chord can serve when used in bar 1. This might solicit answers like: it can be a ii chord in a ii-V-I, it can be a vi chord in a vi-ii-V-I, it can be a i chord in a i-iv progression, etc.

Comment: What is your voicing of Dm(add9) ?

Comment: I wrote a song whose verse progression is :G Dm(add9) X 4, F#m7 Em F#m7 G6, F#m7 Em D C B. G -> Dm(add9) sounds good, Dm(add9) ->  F#m7 is very interesting: the A and E stay constant, D -> C# and F -> F#.

Comment: Nice! I'll try this out

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.basicmusictheory.com/d-minor-triad-chords) You will find all the triad chords contained in a Dm key. Try playing around those chord and you might found something inspiring. However, I would not personally spend to much time on this as the result might end up really conventional and boring. when you are feeling comfortable try going of book and for example voice your chords in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more modern/popular type of song, I'm fairly sure that Drive by Incubus uses that chord. It is also prevalent in jazz all over the place.